# $.Ajax doesnt work in windows8 metro app

Tags: html, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to migrate my existing html5 app into a metro app, and finding two major hurdles:

1. .innerHtml is not supported due to security reason
2. $.Ajax just doesn't work (I am using jsonp for data exchange from server)

Questions:

1. How do I bypass the security issue for .innerHtml?
2. What other alternative do I have to make $.Ajax work?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: You aren't supposed to use jQuery AJAX or normal AJAX in WinJS. IIRC there is a special xhr object you must use instead (which means you don't need JSONP, just JSON).

Comment: This is better answered in another stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859523/using-jquery-with-windows-8-metro-javascript-app-causes-security-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q2: I had the similar problem, and I changed my $.get to:

```
function getJSON(url, data, callback, errorCb) {
if (data != null)
{
    var params = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        params.push(key + "=" + encodeURI(data[key]));
    }
    url += "?" + params.join("&");
}

WinJS.xhr({ url: url }).then(
    function (result) {
        if (callback != null)
            callback(result.response, result.status);
    },
    function (result) {
        if (errorCb)
            errorCb(result.status);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: WinRT block throws exceptions or warnings when you use `.innerHtml` for dynamic content. But they don't block you from using `.innerHTML` all the time. Have you tried `toStaticHTML` method like following:

```
element.querySelector("#myId").innerHTML = "some string" + toStaticHTML(yourHTMLContent);
```

Q2: regular javascript `xhr` call works for me. Actually I believed that I used `.ajax` to send some simple `GET` or `POST` request before, but ended up using `xhr` for some other reasons

Hope this helps.