# JavaScript runtime error Incorrect function - The strangest errors

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing a Windows 8 app using Javascript. I got this problem when testing my app using Windows 8 emulator. This seems a bug of ui.js.

```
Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 22600, column 25 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0.rc/js/ui.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely cont
```

It points to this line.

```
that._viewport.style.opacity = 1.0;
```

Console log

```
SCRIPT5007: Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 22600, column 25 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0.rc/js/ui.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
File: ui.js, line: 22600 column: 25
```

**Update:**
Today 2012/08/09. When I run my app, it generates one more strange error in jquery.js and ui.js. What's wrong with them???

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/1.0)'. 
Exception was thrown at line 5200, column 4 in ms-appx://7034140f-baab-4c76-b27c-2a4c76641550/js/jquery.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 28908, column 30 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0.rc/js/ui.js
0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Incorrect function.
```

Comment: So the error says that `that._viewport` is undefined. Have you checked what `that._viewport` reference to at this line. Maybe you should shows soem more code.

Comment: That file is from Windows SDK. How could it throws an exception? :-S

Comment: do you u have an encapsulated test case you can pop onto dropbox or the like?  What's the code you have written that results in the error?

Comment: My app loads content from cloud and even uses JQuery. I think JQuery is the problem. I don't know why sometimes when starting my app, it crashes and throws it. I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859523/using-jquery-with-windows-8-metro-javascript-app-causes-security-error but it still generates some strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is a known bug in WinJS in the RC build of Windows 8. The good news is that the bug is fixed in the RTM build.

Comment: If it's a bug, how to get a free fix for developer now?

Comment: The RTM build is available on MSDN.

Comment: ... and it requires .NET Framework 4.5.5 (not free for developer)

Comment: The download page for developing apps for the Windows 8 Store is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx). There is a link to a free trial of Windows 8 RTM on that page.

Comment: I don't see a link for Visual Studio RTM. Could you give the full URI? The download page shows "There is no subscription associated with your Live ID. Add a subscription to this account."

Comment: This is off topic. You're asking product support questions now. The original question is answered: It's a bug in WinJS.

Comment: I still get "0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError"
in Windows 8 Professional RTM.