# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content in Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this error when run my app in VS I used query file but I cant solved that error until now
text about error issue from here code

```
u.appendChild(n).appendChild(d)
```

> Unhandled exception at line 3, column 12463 in
>   ms-appx://90e9bf82-2f1d-4744-98d6-00d6c0fe26dd/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
>
> 0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content.
>   A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously
>   modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the
>   innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this
>   exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or
>   explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as
>   createElement.  For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

at my SkyDrive I have image of error and source code of jquery-1.9.1.min 
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=782083c12ddbc730&id=782083C12DDBC730%21143

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery with Windows 8 Metro JavaScript App causes security error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859523/using-jquery-with-windows-8-metro-javascript-app-causes-security-error)

Answer (score 1):

I have made following changes in my code. 
Use "**jquery-2.0.0.js**" or "**jquery-2.0.0.min.js**" in your project, instead of " jquery-1.9.1.min".

Still you want to use " **jquery-1.9.1.min**" then you need to customize your js so that it will work for windows 8 app.

Comment: use my file "jquery-2.0.0.js" from following link:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dvgdrhd4opxddg/jquery-2.0.0.js